# regex match where string doesn't occur

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following test set, I want the 1st and 4th line to match:

```
/src/main.ts
/node_modules/vue-runtime-helpers
/node_modules/.pnpm/vue-runtime-helpers@1.1.2/node_modules/vue-runtime-helpers/dist/normalize-component.mjs
/node_modules/.pnpm/tslib@2.0.3/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js
```

Usually a regex like this would suffice: `/node_modules\/(?!vue-runtime-helpers)/`, but this still matches the 3rd line.

What regex do I need to exclude lines 1-3?

Comment: So, you do not want to match Line 1?

Comment: basically I want to exclude all lines where "node_modules" occurs, but include those lines if "vue-runtime-helpers" occurs.

Comment: Then use `^(?!.*node_modules\/vue-runtime-helpers).*node_modules\/` - https://regex101.com/r/UxLvwd/1. Or, simplifying as per your comment suggestion, ``^(?!.*vue-runtime-helpers).*node_modules``